# Process text content in a xml tag , compare it with some text and if needed edit content using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml file with content which looks something like this:

```
<a id = 123123> 
    <title>Metadata of Architecture</title>
    <entry valign="top" colname="col1" morerows="0">
        <p>Attribute</p>
    </entry>
    <p><b>attribut2 some more text</b></p>
    <p><i>attrbut3 has normal text</i></p>
</a>
```

need an xslt

I want to process all available text content in the xml file, mainly which is present in  "p" tags[even title tag has text]. Like i wan fetch "Attribute" then compare it with a string then decide whether i wan keep it as it is or change it .
   Like wise "attribut2 some more text" has to be picked one by one "attribut2" "some" "more" separately and compared.

In short where ever the text information is present , it has to be picked compared to string and edited if needed.[every single word in the whole file ]

output expected :

```
<a id = 123123> 
    <title>Metadata of Architecture</title>
    <entry valign="top" colname="col1" morerows="0">
        <p>Attribute</p>
    </entry>
    <p><b>attribut2 common common common</b></p>
    <p><i>attrbut3 common common common</i></p>
</a>
```

need a good xsl transforamtion xml-- xml
thanks in advance

Comment: "*compare it with a string*" Where will this string be coming from? What does it look like in your example above? -- Also state XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Comment: Its XSLT 1.0, the comparing is another big headache for me.For now ,the first step is to travese to each and every text (every word) in xml file. Its filtering out common english words,replacing [is,an,the,or,and...] with [common]

Comment: This is not going to be easy, because XSLT 1.0 has no concept of *word* as such. If you merely select a space as the word delimiter, you will end up with "cat", "Cat" and "cat," being three different words.

Comment: Thank you Michael.. But :( There are chances of having huge paragraphs with many words,the main is to filter them out. What about XSLT 2.0 , will it make things easier?

Comment: I believe so, because then you can use regex (which I am not good at, but I believe it's a must in this case).

Comment: Ok,Thank you.I have another question,in the above xml file given i need a xslt to traverse to every p tags present. Iterate to every p tag and edit its text content.We can assume to have single words in every p tag as its content. example : <p>From</p>   <p>This</p> . So that text content which matches a string "This" is replaced by common and the rest are untouched.

Comment: That should be fairly trivial. Where is your difficulty with implementing it?